# Calling a function from HTML

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Notifications
    <span class="badge badge-light"></span>
</button>
```

python:

```
def notif():
    not_num = False
    if count > 0:
        return count
    else
        return not_num

def count():
    return 8
```

Can I get a way to call `"notif"` function into HTML body?

What I want is to do an `"if"` inside an HTML button that tells me how many notifications I have and if I don´t have any, it doesn´t show me anything.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use built-in `if` template tag.

Something like:

```
{% if notifications %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Notifications ({{ notifications|length }})
        <span class="badge badge-light"></span>
    </button>
{% else %}
    No notifications.
{% endif %}
```

This way it will show you the button if you have notifications.

For more info read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if)

You can also create custom template tags for more complex problems, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags)

Comment: Hi @Lunargenta if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.